# Package.json and/or node_modules in Sub Folder

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Is it possibe to use package.json in a sub-folder on my site, but have it work on the top level?  For example, let's image that this is my folder structure:

```
assets
  -- css
  -- js
  -- img
...
// other folders and files
...
node_modules
package.json
```

What I would like to do is create a folder - let's say I call it `dev` and place my package.json file in there.  I then install, uninstall, etc. all of my npm packages from within the dev folder, but have it operate on my files and folders within the `assets` folder.

In other words, this would be the new folder structure:

```
assets
  -- css
  -- js
  -- img
...
// other folders and files
...
dev
  -- node_modules
  -- package.json
```

If this is possible, does it need any special set up?  Will it cause any problems?  I am personally used to always have my `package.json` file at the root level, but would like to move down a level if possible.

**NOTE:**  My goal is simply to clean up my root directory.  That is why I want to **move** `package.json` and `node_modules` to a sub-folder.

Comment: why do you need multiple files ? what is the problem you are facing ? maybe there is a simpler solution ?

Comment: I don't need multiple files.  I just want to MOVE my package.json and node_modules folder to a sub-folder so that I can clean up my root directory.  I edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: I've wanted to do this for a while now too. Have you found any way to do this?